Cannot find module '@teambit/toolbox.performance.v8-cache'
When I run the following command: bit create react hello-1
An anomaly has occurred:
Bit received an error loading bitdev.general/envs/bit-env@1.0.3, due to the error:
"Cannot find module '@teambit/toolbox.performance.v8-cache'".
This is required for the component: unknown
Please use the '--log=error' flag for the full error.
try running "bit install" to fix this issue
I cann't create a component...
Environment

bvm@1.0.4
bit@1.7.17
node@20.11.0
pnpm@9.3.0

@teambit/toolbox.performance.v8-cache is exist in npm registry.
and  bit install can success.
I expect a component can be created successfully.

can you please edit and provide more details on how to reproduce the issue? for example, if this is a new project, how did you start this project, what is the config in the workspace.jsonc file and such. as currently i am not able to reproduce the issue

I am a new biter, only just begin referenced document . I make a empty folder and run bit init bit create react hello-1, at this time, error has occurred. the workspace.jsonc is defult

I use friends mac that no bit installed, and when i install bit, the error occurred yet.

if you run bit capsule delete --all and then run the create command, does it work?
